# how to print only last line in python

Tags: python

Python beginner here. Using 3.8.3. I clicked IDLE -> python shell opened -> clicked file and opened new file to write code.
Image attached
Question: How do i only print the last line in python shell without printing all previous entries?

example: In attached image i am only trying to print "test" but it prints all previous entries like this..
== RESTART: C:/Users/sd3083/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/test.py ==
Hello World
x =  10
y =  10
test

[python script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ujauw.png)

Comment: You could comment out (`#`) the other lines but the one you want. Read more [here](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/comments/comments-in-python/)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please post your code here as text, not as an image so we can easily test.

Comment: Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to print the final line, you'd have to comment out the other print statements. To do this, just add a `#` before the other print statements so your script looks like this:

```py
# print("Hello World")
x = 5
y = 10
x = y
# print("x = ", x)
# print("y = ", y)

print("test")
```

Alternatively you can just delete the print statements you don't want.